Questions about [cytoscape] seem mostly off topic and the surrounding community doesn't seem to understand the site
There has been previous discussion of the cytoscape tag which establishes why there might be on-topic questions about this platform. For reference, the tag description:

Cytoscape is an open source software platform for visualizing complex networks and integrating these with any type of attribute data. Various apps are available for different problem domains, including bioinformatics, social network analysis, and semantic web.

The issue is that a large fraction of questions here seem to be off-topic judged on their individual merit. They come across as support requests - and it's notable in the previous discussion that they seem to be outsourcing support to here (as well as this place which seems to be running custom software). At any rate it's hard to see what these questions (at least, the ones not also tagged as cytoscape-js) generally have to do with programming: which is to say, it's not clear how the OP's use of the platform is intended to relate to a programming task, in many individual cases.
Looking through a sampling of recent questions I see many that were closed by the community as not about programming; at least one that seems to be about using someone else's "plugin" on the platform with no indication that such use involves writing any code ("when i try to load my custom data [following a tutorial by the plugin authors] my custom data doesnt show in the panel" - the question contains no code, only poorly formatted input); a question that's just "how do I do a visualization that looks like this?"; a question about why graph edges appear undirected when imported from a certain source; a question that asks how to run a particular .jar file in a certain environment (unclear how this file relates to the platform); etc.
Basically none of these questions, in other words, show any code in any programming language.
It seems like the platform may not have properly understood policy for doing product support on Stack Overflow. My perception here is not helped by certain stats about the tag. Of the 550 or so questions thus tagged (fewer than are tagged cytoscape-js, incidentally), over 30% have been answered by one specific user - who seems to have had this account (for 9 years now) specifically and solely to answer questions thus tagged. The same user is also active in comments on other questions in the tag, and generally seems to have gone years without any real understanding of how the site generally works - in particular, these answers are habitually "signed" and have a conversational tone.
I feel like questions of this sort should be asked on bioinformatics.SE instead (and that the Cytoscape organization should recommend using that instead).

This has some code in it, but that is the exception.

Did you mean [tag:cytoscape.js]? There are no questions tagged [tag:cytoscape-js]

Related: More actively discourage third-party product support on Stack Overflow

What does the bioinformatics.SE meta say about it and did we contact the Cytoscape organization already? If so, what did they answer?

I've asked a question about this on Bioinformatics Meta. Let's see what they say. Can I ask that people here on Stack Overflow hold off on any mass closure or deletion for a few days? We might want to act differently depending upon what the Bioinformatics folks suggest we do.

In any case, I think we are certainly going to want to reach out to Scooter and the Cytoscape team and ask them to change their docs. Their docs currently say: StackOverflow -- Search and ask questions about software installation, operation and troubleshooting. Be sure to tag your question with "cytoscape" so we can find it!. That seems to me like it's explicitly inviting users to post installation and usage questions here with no programming element to them. (We can also ask them to stylise "Stack Overflow" properly!)

Does this answer your question? Why is Cytoscape on topic?

@DanielA.White No, because this is about an overall impression formed from individual questions judged on their individual merits. The other question is about the concept behind the tag, in principle.

"over 30% have been answered by one specific user - who seems to have had this account (for 9 years now) specifically and solely to answer questions thus tagged" he sounds like a valuable member of the community, none of these things are negatives.

The votes to close this as a duplicate are pretty frustrating. Karl acknowledged the previous question in his first paragraph and explained clearly in the question and again in the comments why the scopes of the questions are different and indeed don't even really overlap. (That one was about whether the tag itself is on-topic, and thus asked, implicitly, whether the tag should exist; this one is about the fact that most of the questions posted under the tag are off-topic, and asks what we should do about that.) Yet still it seems likely now this will get closed and need reopening.

Just a quick note on this tag: I've come across it independently in my editing work. I have also noticed that there is one maintainer who is answering questions - that is good in its own right, but I've asked them many times to stop signing their posts. I've been ignored, and the signatures continue to be added. I'm editing them out five at a time now.

(I agree it is a small thing, but I take a fairly hard line on prolific contributors who won't engage with the community or pay heed to its principles).

@halfer yes, that was part of my observation as well. You certainly have in mind the same maintainer that I credit with answering 30% of questions.

I've just sent this email to John "Scooter" Morris, the main answerer in this tag, on his UCSF email address listed publicly at https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/home/scooter/:

Subject: Meta Stack Overflow discussion about the Cytoscape tag
Hi Scooter!
There's a discussion on Meta Stack Overflow (the site where we discuss
community governance issues relating to Stack Overflow) that I'd like
to draw your attention to:
Questions about [cytoscape] seem mostly off topic and the surrounding community doesn't seem to understand the site
In short, Karl has noticed and flagged up to the community on Meta
that the Cytoscape docs at
https://cytoscape.org/documentation_users.html encourage users to post
questions about installing and using Cytoscape on Stack Overflow, and
don't limit this suggestion in any way to programming-related
questions. As a consequence, it seems like most of the questions on
Stack Overflow tagged with [cytoscape], including plenty you've
answered personally, have not been programming-related. Since Stack
Overflow is specifically meant for programming problems
(https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), those
non-programming-related questions about installing or using Cytoscape
are off-topic, and the community may well close them en masse in due
course.
Other sites in the Stack Exchange network do exist where Cytoscape questions that are off-topic on Stack Overflow would be likely to be on-topic, including Bioinformatics
Stack Exchange (https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) and Super
User (https://superuser.com/). They do have their own scope
restrictions, though; in particular, Super User doesn't accept questions about programming.
(I recognise that these restrictions on topicality are probably kind
of annoying to someone who has a special interest in a topic like
Cytoscape that straddles the topic areas of multiple Stack Exchange
sites. I also recognise that to someone who doesn't actively use Stack
Overflow for  much else, these restrictions in scope may seem
arbitrary and pointless; indeed, I find them frustrating from time to
time myself, when dealing with questions that straddle the scope of
multiple sites or are in a grey area at the edge of a site's scope.
Nonetheless, the limits exist for good reason and the community
enforces them. For one thing, some elements of how the site works -
like the question closure reasons or the guidance on how to write a
good question - are specifically tailored to programming; for another,
the segregation of the Stack Exchange sites by topic allows distinct
communities to form with their own rules and quality standards, limits
the initial audience of most questions to the community they're posted
in so those standards can be applied, and makes the rep system and
other participation incentives like badges less meaningless than they
would be in a world where the platform was more open-ended.)
Before reaching out to you, I did seek some input on Bioinformatics
Meta (i.e. the site where the Bioinformatics Stack Exchange community
discusses governance issues):
https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/stack-overflow-is-unhappy-about-its-cytoscape-tag-what-would-this-community.
They have confirmed they would be very happy to host any and all
questions about Cytoscape except for ones that explicitly make clear
they are using it in a non-bioinformatics context.
Could you please change the guidance at
https://cytoscape.org/documentation_users.html to avoid pointing users
to Stack Overflow with questions that are off-topic there? (I'm
guessing you have the ability to change that docs page yourself; if
not, could you please get in touch with whoever from the Cytoscape
team does have that ability?) Ultimately it's up to you whether you
want to point them to Bioinformatics Stack Exchange (as the community
there has indicated they would welcome), or to Biostars, or maybe to
list various sites, including Stack Overflow, and indicate what's on-topic on each. The only
thing I think the Bioinformatics Stack Exchange folks would want me to
ask of you is that if your docs direct users to Bioinformatics Stack
Exchange, they also warn them that questions mustn't explicitly be
about using Cytoscape in a context unrelated to bioinformatics.
If you'd like to weigh in on either of the Meta discussions, that
would also be welcome!
One disclaimer: I'm not a moderator, haven't run this email past
anyone from the Stack Overflow community before sending it, and don't
speak from any position of authority. I believe I speak for the
broader Stack Overflow community in this email and that it expresses
their wishes, but to check that belief, I'll quote it in the Meta
Stack Overflow discussion and let them weigh in.
Cheers,
Mark Amery (just a person who posts of Stack Overflow a bunch)

I'm also going to go on a quick editing spree purging his signature (mentioned in the question) from his answers, and linking to the Meta Stack Exchange policy about signatures in the edit summary, as I do every time I encounter a post with signatures. That'll at least instantly resolve one issue!

Excellent community work Mark. Let me know if you need a hand with the sigs.

@halfer No need; I've zapped 'em all. I just hope nobody gets grumpy at me for bumping dozens of old questions. I know there are people who dislike rapid bulk edits because they have that effect... but I'm never sure what else one can reasonably do!

Great work. I think with the rate they were being added, and despite prevailing advice, we can get a pass for bulk editing. I too am careful of it, but I push a bit harder if I think the OP needs a helpful nudge.

I prefer setting a good precedent over the minor inconvenience of old questions becoming active. The latter is a choice of the site designers, it is not your choice. Frankly, I think the site needs to cut that out but when have the site owners last shown an interest in making things better... We need this because people don't care to learn what they should or should not do, they just... do. So all we can hope is that it is monkey see, monkey do and not only monkey do.

Hi Mark, as a mod on Bioinformatics, I just wanted to drop by and thank you for the really exemplary way you handled this. From the meta post here, to the one you opened over at Bioinformatics, to the tone of your email, give this man a cookie! Cheers! :)

Um, sorry to cause so much concern.  We have a team meeting tomorrow and I'll discuss this at the meeting.  I suspect that we'll be more than happy to update our documentation and to recommend that folks post on bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.
Sorry for all the noise.

I brought this up at our team meeting and we've updated all mention of Stack Overflow to now point to bioinformatics.stackexchange.com.  I would, indeed, be very helpful if posts with the Cytoscape tag could be migrated there to preserve history.   Thanks!

Thanks for this, Scooter, looking forward to seeing your helpful answers on [bioinformatics.se]! Since that site is not very active and doesn't have a vibrant Meta community, please feel free to contact me (I'm a mod there) if you need any clarification on the scope or anything else. You can always find me in the [unix.se] chat room /dev/chat since the Bioinformatics one isn't really used. Just ping me there or invite me to a room if you want anything from the Bioinformatics mods.

@ScooterMorris RE: "I would, indeed, be very helpful if posts with the Cytoscape tag could be migrated there to preserve history." — this is unfortunately not possible even with the tools available to moderators. Posts can be migrated to another Stack Exchange site only if they're not older than 60 days. However you may try directly contacting Staff using the "Contact Us" form and make your case with them. They'll see internally if they can make this happen.
